# Release .Net Core Apps on GitHub Automated

Tags: github, .net-core, devops, github-actions

I wan't to make .Net Core App in a GitHub Repos that builds automized and pushes the binaries of the build zipped to a new Release, but I have no idea to set this on GitHub up. 
So for example I have my .Net Core Console Application and pull my branch with changes into master. Now the build should start(thats what I have) after the build the binaries should be zipped and attached to a new Release, so there would be continious new Releases.

Hopefully someone understand and can Help.

Here is my workflow till now

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.201
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
```

Comment: You would need to use some tool like VSTS( azure devops) or Jenkins

Comment: @DeepakMishra Sorry I think you miss understand me or I underrated my goal I don't want to deploy the App to any Service, Git Hub has a Release feature where You can manually upload some binaries etc. and realese from this page you can also download the release but I dont want to manual upload my binaries.

Comment: You can attach post build event from the project properties or .csproj file. Then you can run your github api from that event.

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly you are trying to upload the bin/release to somewhere on github. You can attach post build event from the project properties or .csproj file. Then you can run your github api from that event. Alternatively you can use tools which will use msbuild/vsbuild tasks on your code and then release to github release. There must be an upload api of github Release.

Comment: @DeepakMishra cool I'll try thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now solved this way thanks to Deepak Mishra

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Zip the Build
      run: zip -r ${{ secrets.ReleaseZipName }} ./AppName/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/ 
    - name: Create Release
      id: create_release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        tag_name: ${{ github.run_number }}
        release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
        body: New Release.
        draft: false
        prerelease: false
    - name: Upload Release Asset
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
        asset_path: ./${{ secrets.ReleaseZipName }}.zip
        asset_name: ${{ secrets.ReleaseZipName }}.zip
        asset_content_type: application/zip
```